# is it good to pass output list as parameter in recursive permutations code

Tags: python

I have a permutations code and I have to return the output list that contains the list of all permutations. For example if I have [0,1] as the input I need to return [[0,1],[1,0]] as the output. To accomplish that I pass output array as a parameter in the recursive call. Is this a good idea or is it better to create a nested function permute_list inside permute that has access to output list always ? Just wanted to know what a good python user should do.

```
import copy

def permute(l):
    """
    Return a list of permutations

    Examples:
       permute([0, 1]) returns [ [0, 1], [1, 0] ]

    Args:
      l(list): list of items to be permuted

    Returns:
      list of permutation with each permuted item being represented by a list
    """
    output = []
    if len(l) == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        permute_list(l,0,output)
    return output
def permute_list(l,ind,output):

    if ind == len(l) - 1:
        a = l.copy()
        output.append(a)
        print(f"{output}")

    for i in range(ind,len(l)):
        l[ind],l[i] = l[i],l[ind]
        permute_list(l,ind + 1,output)
        l[i],l[ind] = l[ind],l[i]
```

Comment: Does your solution work? I would use one of the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) *Combinatoric iterators*.

Comment: Or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html#permutations

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked your code for accuracy but to answer your question, there does not seem to be an issue with how `output` is being handled. `output` is a list and given that in python variable names serve as references to the object, passing it as a parameter should have no impact on your stack length.